# SharePoint designer 2013 workflow "send email" not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

We created normal workflow "Send email" using SharePoint 2013 workflow. But we are not receiving emails. We tried same with SharePoint 2010 workflow and its working. We also tried alerts me on the list and sharing site, everything working fine means we are receiving emails. Except SharePoint 2013 workflow emails sending to mailbox are coming. Start task process workflow also created and also all tasks has been completed successfully but email are not received.

We checked SMTP server, everything configured correctly.
User Profile full sync was working fine and users are syncing from AD.

Note:We are suing SharePoint 2013 environment.

SP experts, Please suggest us.

Comment: Are you sending emails to external users (means email ids which do not have access on SharePoint)?

Comment: No. Inside users only.

Comment: Is there any antivirus installed on the smtp server? please check it's logs. I have seen issues where antivirus blocks sending of emails.

Comment: No issue with AntiVirus. Because alert emails we are receiving. Only issue workflow 2013 email notification.

Comment: Beside sending email, is workflow 2013 works for other actions? Like update a list item, call a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if "send mail" action does not work in both SharePoint workflow 2010 platform and SharePoint 2013 platform.

Please add the actions "log to history" before and after action "send mail" to check if the send mail action is performed.

And you can also add "pause for a duration" before the "send mail" action, see if it could help.

You may also check if there are some related ULS log.

And also try to hard code the email id rather picking from AD... and see the result.

Reference URL :

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/3c76459c-01f5-4d75-be17-ee5b2ce1c1dd/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-not-sending-emails?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Hi @Habibur, As i said its working for 2010 platform. but its not working for 2013. We tried above condtions and getting same error as "An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["1"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["859"],"SPRequestGuid":[""],"request-id":[""],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS"    Please suggest us.

Comment: Ooh ok... as we know SharePoint 2013 runs on different framework i. e. workflow manager... so can you please check from CA whether the workflow manager is showing as connected from manage service in the server page..... and also try to create sample notification workflow using sp 2013 workflow template... make sure in the wf template selection you are getting 2013 template.

Comment: And also please check the web application where you are trying is connected with workflow manager proxy connection service.. go to WA setting then from the ribbon service connections

Comment: Workflow Manager connected in CA. Tested sample Send email using 2013 workflow. Same issue we are getting. i am not getting second comment. please explore. Thank you..

Comment: @Murali : My second command was about, if we go all web application page from CA.. then select the particular web application where you are running the wf... go to ribbon near general settings... click on proxy connection or something connection related I do not now remember the exact name... then one pop up window will be opened... there we can see what are the service connections are enabled for that wa... need to ensure here wf proxy connection is checked.